# Is it possible to synchronize data members and not methods?

Tags: java

After reading topics here about Java synchronized methods, I've tried to implement it in my multiplayer game because many threads are opened and trying to access the same resource.
I've made methods synchronized but that's doesn't help me since if I have a data member called ArrayList clientConnection; and the methods that are available are:

```
int getArrayListSize() {
    clientConnection.size();
}

void addConnection(ServerConnection i_connection) {
    clientConnection.add(i_connection);
}

void removeConnection(ServerConnection i_connection) {
    int index = clientConnections.indexOf(i_Connection);
    clientConnections.remove(index);
}

ServerConnection getClientFromArrayListByIndex(int i_Index) {
    ServerConnection client = this.clientConnections.get(i_Index);
}
```

I've tried to make a global synchronized method to whenever one want to use one of the methods he needs to pass in an operation type and other data and he locks the function.
The problem is that there are 2 function that return void, 1 returns int and 1 returns ServerConnection so I can't create that global method.
My question if there is a possible to lock data members and not methods in Java so I can lock the clientConnection data member?
Thanks.

Comment: Looks to me that `getArrayListSize` and `getClientFromArrayListByIndex` do not belong to a public interface of your object.  If you could show us what would be the actual usage, we could have steered you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can synchronize a function by using the `synchronized` keyword.  For example:

```
synchronized ServerConnection getClientFromArrayListByIndex(int i_Index) { 
    ServerConnection client = this.clientConnections.get(i_Index);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The problem I have with that that one thread can remove a server connection from clientConnection arrayList and in the same time another thread tries to get the arraylist size or to get the serverconnection object in that specifiec index that was removed and that's not ok

Comment: Then you should manually specify a lock object.  You can synchronize based on the `clientConnection` ArrayList, and only one thread will be able to access that object at a time.  The general rule of thumb is to synchronize on the resource that is shared (and therefore the cause of the potential problem).  You could also look into using conncurrent data structures.

Comment: This scenario might cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, but it won't leave the list in an indeterminate state due to a concurrency problem. Just document the method correctly, and/or make it return null if the index is not valid anymore, and/or throw a custom exception rather than the default ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the index is not valid anymore.

Comment: you say I can lock the arraylist?

Comment: Yes, by simply wrapping accesses to the ArrayList in `synchronized(clientConnections) { ... }` blocks. But as others have mentioned in this answer and in others, you will also need to consider the performance. Ideally, what would you like to have happen if there is contention for this shared resource? For example, you could use a BlockingQueue, which will essentially just queue up the operations. If there is a remove performed first, then a read, the read operation will need to wait until the remove has completed. But then some client could just be stuck waiting. In a game, that's really bad.

Comment: Don't consider performance at this stage. The operations you're doing in the synchronized blocks are very fast, and I doubt you would have a measurable impact by making every access to the list synchronized.

Comment: I have two arraylists which are the main objects that all threads will access (get,set,update,indexOf,etc..) how do I declare and use synchronized in this case, can I get an example please ? thanks alot

Comment: Well, firstly, do NOT synchronize on both objects.  This can potentially cause your code to deadlock.  The easiest thing for you to do would probably be to analyze how best to use Java's concurrent data structures to handle this trickery for you.  Perhaps @JBNizet's suggestion is true; first you can get the basics down and provide a naive implementation of the class(es) you're trying to implement.  Then you can worry about performance later.

Comment: Well, it's one class called Server which holds a list of gametables(rooms) and list of connected players. everyime one join the server, he gets added to the list, leaves then removed from the list and ofcourse there is search by index etc...

Comment: @JB Nizet, do you have any example for me how to implement what your saying with 2 arraylists I have in my server class?

Comment: The two arraylists constitute the shared state of your Server class. synchronize every method that accesses any of these two array lists. And make sure you never pass or return any of those lists to other objects, as they could then access them without synchronization. If you must return os pass them, make a copy first and pass/return the copy.

Comment: @JB Nizet, if I synchronize the methods like getArrayListSize() and AddToList() and removeFromList() and if one thread access addToList method and a second access the removeFromList(), can both operations on the arraylist be done ? they are accessing different methods..

Comment: Re-read my answer: if two methods foo and bar are synchronized (on the same object), only one thread can execute any of those methods. If one thread executes foo, all the other threads must wait before being able to call foo or bar.

Answer (score 3):

If you make all these methods synchronized, then only one thread at a time will be able to invoke any of the methods, and the list will thus be accessed in a thread-safe way, provided only these methods are able to access the list (i.e. the list is private, and no other method uses the list).

```
synchronized int getArrayListSize() { ... }
synchronized void addConnection(ServerConnection i_connection) { ... }
etc.
```

Comment: the problem with that that I need more methods that can access the list, like removing a connection or iterating for finding a connection...

Comment: synchronize those methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one class you can simply prefix your methods with `synchronized`; then there is only one thread in any of those methods. But please think if you need this really; it could slow the execution. If you have public fields you should make them private and create getter methods.

Comment: That was a gernal note; you should not make all methods of all classes synchronized. You should think about it. But better correct than fast is also in my opinion.

Comment: making all methods synchronized will slow the application right ? what do I do if have different type of operations on the same arraylist and for example: add,remove,getsize etc... if I have 3 threads and each one uses a different method in the same time, that can cause a big problem.

Comment: You can use a synchronizedList or synchronize over the arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Collections.synchronizedList()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) to wrap your `List` in one for which all of the methods are synchronized.

Whether this is better than synchronizing the methods in your class depends on what else your methods do, and if those things also need to be coordinated.

Comment: That's sounds like a great solution, do you have an example of usage?

Comment: Except in the removeConnection() method, which could fail - it performs two operations that are synchronized for each call, but aren't an atomic unit (and need to be).  There's a chance another thread could modify the list between the indexOf() and remove() call.

Comment: I didn't spot what was happening in `removeConnection()`---given the code there, this would create a race condition and hence not be appropriate. I did mention that whether this is appropriate does depend on what else happens in the methods, however...

Comment: @Todd `removeConnection(...)` could be trivially rewritten to use `List#remove(Object o)`, in which case this would not be a problem.

Comment: Not to mention that the `getClientFromArrayListByIndex(...)` call poses some significant locking challenges to any list-based implementation.

Comment: I have two arraylists I use to hold gametables and connections(sockets) and my methods are: add,remove (which iterates throught the arraylist until he finds the right connection to remove and then removes it, getSize and getConnection by index) should I use collections.synchronizedList() or copyonwritearraylist?